# DataTables dataTables_wrapper is not loading

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datatables

In my WordPress v5.5.1, I have a custom post type archive page to show all the posts. For this feature, we wanted to use the `DataTable`. Have enqueued the DataTable files as below:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // deregistered default jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jq', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), null, true); // for Bootstrap
// DATATABLES
wp_enqueue_script('js', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js', array('jq'), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('wp-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jq'), null, true);
wp_enqueue_style('css', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css');
```

In my scripts.js file which is being loaded, I have enabled the DataTables as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#songs').DataTable();
});
```

Below is the HTML table:

```
<table id="songs" class="table dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Songs</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Song 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Song 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Song 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Song 4</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

DataTable css files and js files are being loaded and styles are applied.

**However the `dataTables_wrapper` is not being loaded**, where we can sort the table content, pagination and search bar. I see only the plain HTML table.

I ran this code in the JSFiddle and works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/0burvh1y/).

I have tried deactivating all plugins and using default WordPress `jquery` as well, but with no luck.

Comment: you get some JS errors in console ?

Comment: No JS errors in console.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your last call to `wp_enqueue_script` sample code or real? The second parameter to that is an absolute URL. If you give it a relative one, it has to live in the WP root next to wp-config (which I'm very certain is legacy and should probably be avoided.) Usually something like `plugins_url( 'js/scripts.js', __FILE__ )` or similar is used, instead.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I have updated the last `wp_enqueue_script` code as is from my theme file. `scripts.js` file is loading, but the datatables wrapper is not loading.

Comment: Since we don't have access to your site, have you put a `window.alert('here');` inside of your `ready()` to make sure it is actually running?

Comment: Yes, can see the alert after the `ready()`.

Comment: Have you tried skipping bootstrap (just temporarily) and using only jQuery, `https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css` and `https//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`? Also, even if you are using Bootstrap, you still need to include the core data table's JS, too, which I'm not seeing in your code.

Comment: Used the below CDN URLs and working fine now:

`https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js`
`https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.css`

Comment: @theKing any feedback is appreciated :) If my answered helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted!

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, my issue was resolved by using different datatables CDN URLs than the previously used.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the below dataTable CDN URLs and DataTables dataTables_wrapper is loading now:

```
wp_enqueue_script('js', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js', array('jq'), null, true);
wp_enqueue_style('css', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.css');
```

Comment: I was facing a similar issue in my .NET application and spent numerous hours debugging why the URLs worked fine on an online code sandbox but not in my project.
Then i found this post. Seems like a weird solution, but i'll take it.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would create functions and link them to actions like the following :

```
function add_datatables_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('datatables', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('datatables');

  wp_register_script('datatables_bootstrap', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('datatables_bootstrap');
}
 
function add_datatables_style() {
  wp_register_style('bootstrap_style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_style');

  wp_register_style('datatables_style', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('datatables_style');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_datatables_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_datatables_style');
```